# Date Picker Highlight day if not Available

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datepicker

I have this online reservation, and i have this problem, Is there a way i can highlight the unavailable days on the date picker?assuming i have inserted dates on the database. Here's my code for the date picker.

```html
<input type="text" name="pick-up-date" id="pick-up-date" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy">
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Yes , is there a way i can highlight or disable the day if it's already reserved?

Comment: I'm gonna try it later, thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `beforeShowDay()` function from jQuery [check this](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay)

e.g., something like this,

```
var datesToDisable = ["2015-01-07","2015-17-07","2015-21-07"]; //you have to fetch the dates and put em in an array and wh7atever the format is.

$('#pick-up-date').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
        return [ datesToDisable.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});
```

Should do the trick!

Comment: How am i gonna fetch the data and make it an array on the javascript?

Comment: well this answer is for disabling the dates as you had asked for. Regarding, "How am i gonna fetch the data and make it an array on the javascript?". If you could show how you are fetching the values from database. What's the tech stack that you are using? Which technology are you using on the server side?